# block google chat server in google app standard

Tags: g-suite

Using squid, I've blocked/regulated successfully gmail talk for users in gmail.com. But still dealing with chat in users under google apps Standard.

any ideas?
thanks in advance

Comment: Just a tip, but you'll want to address Google Chat in iGoogle, too.  Google Chat is blocked in Gmail here, but the work around is to use iGoogle. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the links that your blogging to be _tcp.yourdomain.com. Or perhaps in your case a wildcard.

From: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34143

> Note: When updating your SRV
>   records with the following
>   information, make sure to replace
>   gmail.com with your domain. However,
>   don't replace google.com.

```
_xmpp-server._tcp.gmail.com. IN SRV 5 0 5269 xmpp-server.l.google.com.
_xmpp-server._tcp.gmail.com. IN SRV 20 0 5269 xmpp-server1.l.google.com.
_xmpp-server._tcp.gmail.com. IN SRV 20 0 5269 xmpp-server2.l.google.com.
_xmpp-server._tcp.gmail.com. IN SRV 20 0 5269 xmpp-server3.l.google.com.
_xmpp-server._tcp.gmail.com. IN SRV 20 0 5269 xmpp-server4.l.google.com.
_jabber._tcp.gmail.com. IN SRV 5 0 5269 xmpp-server.l.google.com.
_jabber._tcp.gmail.com. IN SRV 20 0 5269 xmpp-server1.l.google.com.
_jabber._tcp.gmail.com. IN SRV 20 0 5269 xmpp-server2.l.google.com.
_jabber._tcp.gmail.com. IN SRV 20 0 5269 xmpp-server3.l.google.com.
_jabber._tcp.gmail.com. IN SRV 20 0 5269 xmpp-server4.l.google.com.
```

> If you require assistance making these
>   changes in your domain host account,
>   we suggest contacting your domain
>   host. Since each domain host has
>   different DNS instructions, Google
>   does not provide support for SRV
>   records. Not all domain hosts offer
>   SRV record modification.

Once you have this information, you can block sites that match a certain pattern in squid

edit: /etc/squid/squid.conf

add the following lines to Access Controls:

```
acl blockregexurl url_regex -i xmpp
http_access deny blockregexurl
```

Source:http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-deny-access-users-to-particular-websites/

Comment: I'm using everydns.com as NS (till not allowing SRV mngmnt). I only have available ipchains and squid...  a box SuSE (using SuSEfirewall2)

Comment: I think the information posted above should give you some insight about what you should block. For instance: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-deny-access-users-to-particular-websites/ for example: acl blockregexurl url_regex -i xmpp
http_access deny blockregexurl